# MAC with sha256 and base64 in unix

Tags: unix

Program is written in VB macro to generate MAC and similar program require to build in Unix to generate with below logic mention :
Can please translate VB macro program into UNix format to generate same Mac value:

Algorithm mentioned in attached image.

Input string : STR
Expected MAC : Mentioned in image

I tried below

echo -n STR | openssl dgst -binary -sha 256 | openssl base64
BUT NOT MATCHING WITH EXPECTED MAC VALUE

[2]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPsSS.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPsSS.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2J3p.jpg)[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Can you specify what is your concrete problem? What part of the code are you having trouble with?

Comment: This is not a MAC (Media Access Control) address, it's a MAC (Message Authentication Code).

Comment: Answer is below: echo -n 'STR' | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac 'STR' -binary | base64

Answer (score 0):

Answer is below:
echo -n 'STR' | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac 'STR' -binary | base64